# Clear Auxiliary Route before navigating to another route. @angular-4.0.2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am using an aux route for popup, toast notifications which clears itself after couple of seconds after successful navigation. during that time the `router.url` equals to `/home(aux:toast)`, and if navigating to another route in that time the url becomes `/detail(aux:toast)`, but what I want is clear the aux route before navigating to another component.

One solution was when navigating to aux route I did following.

```
this.router.navigate([{outlets: {aux: 'toast'}}], {skipLocationChange: true})
```

this didnt changed the address bar url, but `router.url` still is `/home(aux:toast)`

and when navigating same thing happens address bar url changes to `/detail(aux:toast)`

Answer (score 0):

Will it work?

```
 router.navigate([{outlets: {aux: null])
```

Comment: this will work, i know, but i want this to happen on before any route change

Comment: hmm, try to add canDeactivate guard and check if outlets not null, do redirect there to a route with outlets null